# Detention and removal of an EU citizen from the UK

Tags: uk, ireland, eu-citizens

I am a Spanish citizen, and I came to the UK in 2017. I was detained because I was rough sleeping, and held in a detention centre. I chose to leave the UK.

When I tried to come back, I was told that I had been administratively removed from the UK and I had been banned for one year. I was held in detention.

Now, I want to travel to Ireland. Are they going to allow me in to Ireland after my removal from the UK?

I have read that the UK and Ireland share information about deportations and removals, and visa applications in a database.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87822/discussion-on-question-by-miss-detention-and-removal-of-an-eu-citizen-from-the-u).

Comment: @JonathanReez OP doesn't have enough reputation to use chat. Will they still be able to view it?

Comment: You can't ...I think..

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Would someone who has downvoted please explain?

Comment: @phoog The OP clarified in comments what their problem was and I edited it. The downvotes were from before I edited it, I think.

Comment: @MJeffryes anyone can view the chat

Answer (score 5):

In principle, you have a right to live in Ireland, as an EU citizen. Your right to enter Ireland is strongly protected by law. However, you are correct in thinking that the UK and Ireland share information about deportations and visas. It is possible that when you enter Ireland, the border officer could become aware of your previous issue in the UK. Legally speaking, it should not be allowed to influence their decision. However, border officers do not always correctly follow the law.

The larger issue, which I discussed in the comments, is that based on what you have told us, I believe that your original removal from the UK was against the law. It should never have happened in the first place. This is because in December 2017, [it was found in court that the policy of deporting rough sleepers who were EU citizens was illegal](https://www.freemovement.org.uk/ngo-victory-home-office-policy-rough-sleepers-found-unlawful/). Although your ban on entry to the UK has presumably now expired, it should never have happened in the first place. Some rough sleepers who were illegally deported from the UK are now [being awarded compensation](https://righttoremain.org.uk/government-to-pay-compensation-to-european-rough-sleepers/) because of how the government treated them.

There are campaigners which helped the people who were deported to get the case heard in court. They are now also helping people who should be given money because of how they were treated. **I cannot say whether you are owed money**. However, you should contact one of the campaigns, such as [North East London Migrant Action](https://nelmacampaigns.wordpress.com/eea-removals-resources/) to see whether they can help you. They may also be able to help reduce the likelihood of a problem when going back to the UK or to Ireland. Their email address is `nelondonmigrantaction@gmail.com`. They may be able to help find a lawyer who can help you for free. Again, I can't guarantee that. You should tell them everything that you told us about what happened to you.

Comment: should note though that the people in this article were working and able to support themselves but rough sleeping. If someone is rough sleeping and not working (i,e, not able to support themselves) the law states there is the right to deport them. Though the UK tends not to use this

Comment: @theotherone I'm not a lawyer, but my understand of the decision was that it was found that using rough sleeping as a factor in the decision to deport was illegal. The Home Office wasn't actually investigating whether people were working or not, they were just using rough sleeping by itself as a reason to deport. For example, they deported a man even though he tried to show them payslips. There's no reason to think that they would have investigated further in OP's case either, since the policy at the time was that rough sleeping=automatic deportation.

Comment: @theotherone the law states that there is a nearly unconditional right to enter and to reside for up to three months.  Removal of someone who is not working and cannot afford to support him- or herself should only be possible after three months, and a prior removal should not affect the right of entry nearly two years later, especially in a different member state.

Answer (score 0):

Ireland could refuse you entry if they believe your conduct has been such that it would be contrary to public policy or would endanger public security. But that's up to them, we can't answer that.

> If you are an EEA or Swiss national, you may be refused permission to
>   enter Ireland only if:
>
> - You are suffering from a specified disease or disability or
> - **Your conduct has been such that it would be contrary to public policy or
>     would endanger public security**

[Citizens Information](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/moving_to_ireland/coming_to_live_in_ireland/permission_to_land_in_ireland.html)

Comment: It should be noted that these restrictions are supposed to apply to much more serious behavior than rough sleeping.  Even prior criminal convictions are not by themselves sufficient to trigger these exceptions.  As noted in the UK case, the restrictions must also be nondisciminatory, so there would have to be a strict policy against rough sleeping imposed on Irish citizens.  If Ireland *did* assert that this person's conduct rose to the level of the public policy or public security exception, Ireland would not likely be able to prevail in court.

Answer (score -7):

So you are a citizen of one of the Schengen signatory nations, traveling to another Schengen signatory nation.

Your deportation and subsequent refusal of entry into a non-signatory nation SHOULD have no influence on your travel plans.
Heck, there's no border between Ireland and Spain, that's what the Schengen treaty created after all.

Of course if you give the Irish authorities reason to investigate you it's quite likely that your previous actions in the UK are going to raise some eyebrows, so you'd best behave yourself over on the Green Isle.

Comment: Ireland is not part of Schengen, there is passport control as Ireland has it's own immigration policy, UK and Ireland also share data. Your answer is completely wrong.

Comment: I have been not deported. I got an administative removal and a 1year ban

Comment: But, i have a question. How things work if you want to go in the UK or Ireland to study? I mean after few years.